# Why do we always obtain expressions independent of trigonometric functions when we implicitly derive their inverses?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, trigonometry, derivatives

**Question**
Why do we always obtain expressions independent of trigonometric functions when we implicitly derive their inverses?
For example, why didn't we just leave $\sin y$ instead of replacing it by $x$?

[image]

Comment: Short answer: because for the derivative of a function of $x$ we'd like to get the answer in terms of the same independent variable $x$. It's not always possible, hence the method of implicit differentiation, where you often see answers still with $y$ in them. But whenever possible, we do like obtaining such explicit formulas, so that we can use them for finding derivatives of many other functions.

Comment: Got it! wonderful !

Comment: Basically in  the Pythagoras thm we are expressing $\cos x$ in terms of $\sin x $ algebraically and taking using reciprocal to compensate for inverse function derivative.

Comment: I don't think zipirovich's comment makes much sense. You could perfectly well say that the derivative of $\arcsin x$ is $\sec(\arcsin x)$. This is equally "explicit" as a function of $x$. The point is that any trig function composed with an inverse trig function can be written purely algebraically.